# Erro em output de variável do tipo int em código dart

Tags: dart

Estou iniciando em código dart antes de ir para o flutter, está acontecendo um erro na linha `var numero = int.parse();` que não dá para inserir um valor inteiro, como devo entrar com um valor inteiro corretamente?

Caso eu queria fazer um `output` com variável do tipo `decimal` como faço para capturar corretamente esse tipo de variável?

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  
  print ("Digite o seu nome: ");
  var nome = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  print ("Digite um número inteiro: ");
  var numero = int.parse(); // ERRO
  
  if (numero > 10) {
    print("${nome}, o número ${numero} é maior que 10.");
  } else if (numero < 10) {
    print("${nome}, o número ${numero} é menor que 10.");
  } else {
    print("${nome}, o número ${numero} é igual a 10.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Caso seja um valor ```decimal```, como devo fazer um ```output``` adequado para esse tipo de variável?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação, o método [`int.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/int/parse.html) deve receber uma string em seu primeiro argumento.

No entanto, você não está passando nenhum valor para que o `parse` possa funcionar (o que causa o erro). Para corrigir, você deve perguntar (também utilizando o `stdin.readLineSync`) a idade do usuário e passar como argumento. Assim:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  
  print("Digite o seu nome: ");
  var nome = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  print("Digite um número inteiro: ");
  var numeroStr = stdin.readLineSync();
  var numero = int.parse(numeroStr); // numero é int
  
  if (numero > 10) {
    print("${nome}, o número ${numero} é maior que 10.");
  } else if (numero < 10) {
    print("${nome}, o número ${numero} é menor que 10.");
  } else {
    print("${nome}, o número ${numero} é igual a 10.");
  }
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-480767#main.dart).</sup>

Você também pode reduzir as duas linhas para uma só. Assim:

```
var numero = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

Vale lembrar que se o usuário passar um valor não numérico, uma exceção será lançada.

Se você quiser fazer o `parse` de um *double* (número com "parte decimal"), pode utilizar o método [`double.parse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html):

```
var numero = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

Pela sua pergunta, você parece estar confundindo `double` com `decimal`. [Tome cuidado porque `float`, `double` e `decimal` são coisas diferentes.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/69296)

Comment: Caso seja uma variável do tipo ```decimal``` como seria ```decimal.parse(numeroStr)```?

Comment: ```Digite o seu nome: 
Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: StdIOUtils._getStdioInputStream```

Comment: Nesse caso você procura pelo método [`double.parse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/parse.html). Cuidado para não confundir `decimal` com `float` ou `double`. Eles têm significados diferentes... Nativamente, o Dart não tem um tipo decimal.

Comment: Como faço para que o valor a ser digitado fique na mesma linha do print? Pra ficar ```Digite o seu nome: Kyukay```.

Comment: @Kyukay, seria ideal você abrir uma outra pergunta para isso. :) Mas utilize `stdout.write` ao invés de `print`, já que este último adiciona um `\n` ao final da string passada. Já 
o `stdout.write`, não.

Comment: deu certo, vlw.